# TensorFlow2.0 Model.fit auc is not equal to the auc obtained by model.predict and then caculating with sklearn roc_auc_score in the same dev set

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, auc

tf2.0, my model show in below code, it‘s auc is about 0.62 in training

```
    def load_dataset(csv_path, shuffle=True):
        return tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
            csv_path,
            batch_size=256,  
            shuffle=shuffle,  
            label_name='label',  
            na_value='?',
            num_epochs=1,
            ignore_errors=True)

    train_data = load_dataset('../data_demo/train/copy1_5train_index.csv')
    train_data = train_data.map(embedding_train)
    dev_data = load_dataset('../data_demo/dev/dev_index.csv')
    dev_data = dev_data.map(embedding_dev)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
    ])

    class_weight = {0: 0.19, 1: 0.81}

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(), tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

    checkpoint_save_path = 'model/dc.ckpt'
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_save_path + '.index'):
        print('--------------load the model-------------')
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_save_path)

    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_save_path,
                                                     save_weights_only=True,
                                                     save_best_only=False)

    model.fit(train_data, epochs=5, class_weight=class_weight, validation_data=dev_data, callbacks=cp_callback)

    model.summary()
```

But, loading model and then calculation auc with sklearn is 0.5, the code showing below

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

def build_predict_result():

    def load_dataset(csv_path, shuffle=True):
        return tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
            csv_path,
            batch_size=1024, 
            shuffle=shuffle,  
            label_name='label', 
            na_value='?',
            num_epochs=1,
            ignore_errors=True)

    def load_vec():
        news_vec = np.load('../data_demo/dev/dev_news_vec.npy')
        user_vec = np.load('../data_demo/dev/dev_user_vec.npy')
        return tf.constant(news_vec, dtype=tf.float32), tf.constant(user_vec, dtype=tf.float32)

    nvec, uvec = load_vec()

    def embedding(x, y):
        return tf.concat([tf.nn.embedding_lookup(uvec, x['uindex']), tf.nn.embedding_lookup(nvec, x['nindex'])],
                         axis=1), y

    dev_data = load_dataset('../data_demo/dev/dev_index.csv')
    dev_data = dev_data.map(embedding)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
    ])

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=['accuracy', 'AUC'])

    checkpoint_save_path = 'model/dc.ckpt'
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_save_path + '.index'):
        print('--------------load the model-------------')
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_save_path)

    result = model.predict(dev_data)
    print(result.shape)

    dev_df = pd.read_csv('../data_demo/dev/dev_index.csv')
    dev_df['predict'] = result
    dev_df.to_csv('dev_index_predict.csv', index=False)

build_predict_result()

def evaluate():
    """
    计算ndcg
    :return:
    """
    df = pd.read_csv('dev_index_predict.csv')
    auc = roc_auc_score(df['label'], df['predict'])
    print('auc: ' + str(auc))

evaluate()
```

I can't find tf2.0 source code that metrics of calculation auc. Through testing tf2.0 and sklearn AUC function with same data like [1, 0, 0, 1], [0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5], their result is equal.

Comment: Can you give a google link for your code ?

Comment: https://github.com/ConstellationBJUT/recommender_system_study

deep_crossing->dc_model.py->def dc2() is model training,
evaluate.py is load model and calculate auc

Comment: Are you using the predicted labels to calculate the AUC? That is, what does the column `df[predict]` have in it? Are they the predicted labels or the probabilities?

Comment: df['predict'] is probability obtained by activation sigmoid of output layer. I tried to convert to one hot, the result has no any change.

Comment: Do you load the right model when you predict data ?

Comment: Model is right, because Model.evaluate(dev_set) function runs right. I can obtain the same accuracy and auc as model.fit(). However, the sklearn roc_auc_score function can not generate the same result as model.evaluate and model.fit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone following my problem. My question is solved. The default of parameter 'shuffle' in function tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset is True. So the prediction result is not correspond to the original csv data. Change 'shuffle' to False solving my problem.

```
    def load_dataset(csv_path, shuffle=False):
        return tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
            csv_path,
            batch_size=1024, 
            shuffle=shuffle,  
            label_name='label', 
            na_value='?',
            num_epochs=1,
            ignore_errors=True)
```